# Is there a convenience method to create a Predicate that tests if a field equals a given value?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, predicate

I often find myself in the need to filter a `Stream` or to use a predicate that checks if a given field has a given value.

Say for example I have this POJO:

```
public class A {
    private Integer field;

    public A(final Integer field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public Integer getField() {
        return field;
    }
}
```

And I want to filter a `Stream` of objects based on the value of the `field`:

```
    final Integer someValue = 42;
    Stream.of(new A(42), new A(1729), new A(42), new A(87539319), new A(null))
            .filter(a -> Objects.equals(a.getField(), someValue))
            ...
```

Would there be a convenience method to generate the predicate for the `filter` method? I noticed there is `Predicate.isEqual` but it does not fit the need.

I could quite easily write one like this:

```
public static <T,R> Predicate<T> isEqual(Function<? super T, ? extends R> f, R value) {
    return v -> Objects.equals(value, f.apply(v));
}
```

and use it as:

```
    Stream.of(new A(42), new A(1729), new A(42), new A(87539319), new A(null))
            .filter(isEqual(A::getField, someValue))
            ...
```

but I'd prefer to reuse an existing method from the JDK if possible.

Comment: Not that I know of. But note that if you know that `someValue` is not `null`, a simple `a -> someValue.equals(a.getField())` is sufficient. It doesn’t look worse than `isEqual(A::getField, someValue)` to me, especially if I consider that `A` is rather a `NameOfARealLifeClass`…

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no such builtin factory method, which you can easily check by looking at [all usages of `Predicate` within the JFC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/function/class-use/Predicate.html) and look for “Methods in … that return Predicate”. Besides the methods within [`Predicate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/function/Predicate.html) itself, there is only [`Pattern.asPredicate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#asPredicate--) which returns a `Predicate`.

Before you’re going to implement such a factory method, you should ask yourself whether it’s really worth it. What makes your lambda expression in `.filter(a -> Objects.equals(a.getField(), someValue))` look complicated, is the use of `Objects.equals` which is not necessary when you can predict for at least one argument whether it is `null`. Since here, `someValue` is never `null`, you can simplify the expression:

```
final Integer someValue = 42;
Stream.of(new A(42), new A(1729), new A(42), new A(87539319), new A(null))
    .filter(a -> someValue.equals(a.getField()))
    …
```

If you still want to implement the factory method and win a price for creatively using what is already there, you can use:

```
public static <T,R> Predicate<T> isEqual(Function<? super T, ? extends R> f, R value) {
    return f.andThen(Predicate.isEqual(value)::test)::apply;
}
```

However, for production code, I’d rather recommend an implementation like this:

```
public static <T,R> Predicate<T> isEqual(Function<? super T, ? extends R> f, R value) {
    return value==null? t -> f.apply(t)==null: t -> value.equals(f.apply(t));
}
```

This factors out the test whether the constant is `null` to simplify the operation that will be performed in each test. So it still doesn’t need `Objects.equals`. Note that `Predicate.isEqual` does similar.

Comment: can you please explain why the `value==null?...`-solution is preferable over `Objects.equals`?

Comment: @Roland: when you call `Objects.equals` in every function evaluation, you will effectively recheck whether `value` is `null` in every function evaluation despite it won’t change. Obviously, the effect will be biggest *if* `value` is `null`, as the resulting function `t -> f.apply(t)==null` will be much cheaper than `Objects.equals`. As you might be using such a utility method a lot of time at different places, the effects accumulate. As said, [`Predicate.isEqual` does similar](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/function/Predicate.java#114)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Oh dear... that was even the reason why I extracted the value in the first place... it's time for the weekend.

Comment: @Holger good idea of using `Predicate.isEqual` rather than `Object.equals`.

Comment: @Holger is there a way to enforce the `R` data type? Because these 2 examples are compilable and yet do not make sense
`.filter(isEqual(a::getField, "some string")` and `.filter(isEqual(a::getField, 12345)`. I wanted to use similar utility function but due to this pitfall it is dangerous. Especially for enums. Solution might be having another `isEqualEnum` with constraint `R extends Enum<R>...` but this is really going to go sideway..

Comment: @PetrÚjezdský there is no way, as it is always possible for the compiler to infer `Object` for `R`. Which combination of classes may lead to a successful `equals` test, depends on the actual implementation of `equals`, two classes may be compatible without having a common base class (other than `Object`). When you change `? extends R` to `R`, you can restrict the arguments when passing existing `Function` implementations. But for the intended use case of passing lambda expressions or method references, this wouldn’t help. Simply said, it accepts arbitrary arguments the same way, `equals` does.

Comment: I just figured it out. Somewhat. If you explicitly define `Function<A, String> FN_A_NAME = A::getName` then you can do `.filter(isEqual(FN_A_NAME, "Peter"))`. And this `.filter(isEqual(FN_A_NAME, 123456))` will not compile. It is cubersome, but for repeated use of same getters this might be useful for someone.

Comment: @PetrÚjezdský that’s what I meant with “when passing existing `Function` implementations”. But when passing method references directly, the compiler is free to infer `Function<A, Object>`. You could also use `(Function<A, String>)A::getName` as method argument. Still, cumbersome.

Comment: A small remark. `Pattern.asPredicate()` isn't the only method outside the `Predicate` interface which allows to obtain a predicate. Java 11 has brought one more predicate-producing method - `Pattern.asMatchPredicate()`.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko well, this answer is seven years old and clearly links to the Java 8 API. Surely, the number of methods is expected grow, but as long as no method matching the question’s issue has been added, it’s not that important.