# Lambda equals using optionals and mappers

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Suppose I have two objects and I want to know if a specific property is equal (nulls are managed exactly as I want):

```
// pre java 8

public static boolean equalsProp(SomeObject a, SomeObject b)
{
    Object aProp = a != null ? a.getProp() : null;
    Object bProp = b != null ? b.getProp() : null;

    return  (aProp == bProp) || (aProp != null && aProp.equals(bProp));
}
```

now that I have java 8, I can rewrite it to be generic:

```
public static <T, U> boolean equals(T a, T b, Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper)
{
    Object aProp = Optional.ofNullable(a).map(mapper).orElse(null);
    Object bProp = Optional.ofNullable(b).map(mapper).orElse(null);

    return (aProp == bProp) || (aProp != null && aProp.equals(bProp));
}
```

But I don't like to define a method like this in one of my classes.

Is there a `java.lang.something.SomeJreBundledClass.equals(a, b, func)` that does exactly this?

Is there a best practice on how to do this (possibly without an utility method)?

---

Maybe it's not clear what I'm asking, I'll try again.

I have this piece of code:

```
Table t1 = ...
Table t2 = ...

if(!my.package.utils.ObjectUtils.equals(t1, t2, Table::getPrimaryKey))
{
    // ok, these tables have different primary keys
}
```

I'm asking if:

- There's a **JRE** class that does the work of `my.package.utils.ObjectUtils`
- There's a better, short and null-tolerant way to compare `t1.primaryKey` and `t2.primaryKey` **without** writing an utility method.

Comment: I highly doubt that there exists a method that does so. Checking whether certain attributes in 2 objects is quite specific. On the other hand, checking whether 2 entire objects are equal is a more sensible proposition and can be done using an inbuilt method

Comment: I understand what you say; but I think it's a very common situation, and it's odd there's nothing bundled to do this kind of comparison in a short way.

Comment: What's the harm in creating a method you just did and using it across your project? Tuples are used very commonly (and every other High level language has them in the standard library) but they aren't present int JAVA :)

Comment: If you are asking for existing method which does described task then I am afraid that your question is off-topic since you are asking for existing tools recommendation.

Comment: @Pshemo I'm not asking for any tool recommendation... I'm asking for a **best practice**, or is this off-topic too?

Comment: @MicheleMariotti Yes, this is off-topic as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: The premise that two null objects should compare equal is questionable. There is published theory that suggests "null == null" should be false. There is existing practice to back this up: for example, null in SQL; and similarly in Java Double.Nan != Double.Nan. Rather than having a method decide for you that null == null, it is safer to force the user to do it manually, thereby forcing them to think about their exact circumstance.

Comment: Java is an object oriented language, watch out that you can't use it as a ore functional language. Sometimes it's better to use the "imperative" way of doing this, it's more easy and more readable.

Comment: I voted to reopen because the clarified part of the question (the edit) is explicit and neutral and doesn't ask for opinion.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't care about it. I needed some information, and you gave it, that's more than sufficient ;)

Comment: Nonetheless, the question, in its second form is a good question for StackOverflow and shouldn't be closed.

Comment: For the record you may also compare `Optional`'s using `equals`: `Optional<U> aProp = Optional.ofNullable(a).map(mapper); Optional<U> bProp = Optional.ofNullable(b).map(mapper); return aProp.equals(bProp);`

Comment: @DidierL what a coincidence: my question is "equivalent" to [yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300011/is-there-a-convenience-method-to-create-a-predicate-that-tests-if-a-field-equals)

Comment: @MicheleMariotti yes I also noticed, a bit different though but similar. I guess we both prefer method references to "complex" lambdas and expressions ;-)

Comment: @DidierL That's for sure :) my problem with complex lambdas is code format and readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm asking if:
>
> - There's a **JRE** class that does the work of `my.package.utils.ObjectUtils`
> - There's a better, short and null-tolerant way to compare `t1.primaryKey` and `t2.primaryKey` **without** writing an utility method.

To your first question, **No** is the answer.

To your second question, **No** is also the answer, unless you're ready to have your code comparing objects quite shadily.

What you're trying to express is the equivalence. Several frameworks can help you use that context. The most notable of which is Guava with its `Equivalence` class/framework. In that case, *you* don't have to write a utility method, because they exist somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this using streams:

```
static class MyClass {
    String prop;

    public String getProp(){
        return prop;
    }
}
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyClass a = new MyClass();
    MyClass b = new MyClass();
    a.prop = "foo";
    b.prop = "foo";
    boolean e = Stream.of(a,b).filter(Objects::nonNull).map(MyClass::getProp).distinct().count() != 2;
    System.out.println("e = " + e);
    a = null;
    b = null;
    e = Stream.of(a,b).filter(Objects::nonNull).map(MyClass::getProp).distinct().count() != 2;
    System.out.println("e = " + e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm talking about. But this is not so short, I wonder if there are other possibilities.

Comment: @Tunaki, did you really read the question? I'm asking if such built-in method **does exist**, not a random built-in equals method, or if there's a way to do this **possibly without an utility method**. So the code in your comment is perfectly acceptable, but you answer wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use something like this:

```
Comparator.comparing(SomeObject::getProp).compare(a, b) == 0
Comparator.comparing(Table::getPrimaryKey).compare(table1, table2) == 0
```