# Composed predicate in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

In Guava, we can do stuff like

```
Predicate<String> isEmpty = Predicates.compose(String::length, Integer.valueOf(0)::equals); // contrived, I know
```

Can we do something similar in Java 8? For example

```
Predicate<Integer> isZero = Integer.valueOf(0)::equals;
Predicate<String> isEmpty = isZero.compose(String::length);
```

or a library function that achives the same?

Note that I'm not asking about how to do this myself (`s -> isZero.test(s.length)` works fine) or why this doesn't work in line (Lambda types are inferred and all that)

Comment: Are you looking for something similar described here -> http://howtodoinjava.com/java-8/how-to-use-predicate-in-java-8/

Comment: There's nothing built-in similar to `Predicates.compose(...)`.

Comment: I think you are looking for functions as first class citizens like in Scala: e.g. `val isZero = (x: Int) => x==0`   `val size = (s:String) => s.length`  `val isEmpty = size andThen isZero`,  which is function composition in the mathematical sense ` f o g (x)`

Answer (score 3):

You can easily write a `compose` method and use that in multiple places:

```
import java.util.function.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer zero = 0;
        Predicate<Integer> isZero = zero::equals;
        Predicate<String> isEmpty = compose(String::length, isZero);

        System.out.println(isEmpty.test("")); // true
        System.out.println(isEmpty.test("x")); // false
    }

    // Composition of a function with a predicate
    public static <T, S> Predicate<T> compose(Function<T, S> first, Predicate<S> second) {
        return input -> second.test(first.apply(input));
    }
}
```

(I removed references to `Integer.ZERO` as that doesn't exist...)

Comment: You don't need to define `compose` for `Function`. It already exists in the `Function` interface - `default <V> Function<V, R> compose(Function<? super V, ? extends T> before)`

Comment: @Eran: Ah, nice, I hadn't seen that :)

Comment: @Jorn: Well you gave an example which *hard-coded* that - whereas I've provided the *reusable* form. It's not clear you knew how to build that - or why you'd care whether the reusable form were in the Java 8 standard library or your own library.

Comment: @Jorn: as written [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33308391/2711488), you *can* use `f.andThen(Predicate.isEqual(value)::test)::apply` if using existing features is all that matters to you. Otherwise, there is nothing wrong with a lambda expression, especially, as it is shorter and more efficient than the supposed factory method. But note that `Predicate<Integer> isZero = Predicate.isEqual(0);` *does* exist.