# How to suitably compose Predicate and Function in a Java function?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference, functional-interface

The purpose is to create a new Predicate usable in a stream filter :

```
myCollectionOfElement
.stream()
.filter(
    MyStaticHelperClass.compose(MyStaticHelperClass.getSubElement1OfTheElement(),MyStaticHelperClass.getPredicate1OnSubElement1()))
.sorted(MyStaticHelperClass.getOtherSubElement().reversed())
.limit(10)
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

`getSubElement1OfTheElement()` returns `Function<E,S>` (E contains a S property)
`getPredicate1OnSubElement1()` returns `Predicate<S>`

I use static functions to expose method references and functions.
I do this because the stream is called in a **Velocity template** and this context **doesn't support lambda syntax and method reference**.
**I don't want to create a static function for all possible combinaisons, so I really want them to be composable**.

For example here, I don't want to have a static `getPredicate1OnElementThatCheckProperty1OnTheSubElement1()` because I can compose `getSubElement1OfTheElement()` and `getPredicate1OnSubElement1()`.

So I need a compose function :

```
// returns a new Predicate constructed by applying Predicate predicate on the result of Function function
public static <E,S> Predicate<E> compose(Function<E,S> function, Predicate<S> predicate)

// most intuitive : lambda
return value -> predicate.test(function.apply(value));

// with method references
return function.andThen(predicate::test)::apply;
// predicate.compose is not available because Predicate interface doesn't extends Function interface
```

inspired by [Is there a convenience method to create a Predicate that tests if a field equals a given value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300011/is-there-a-convenience-method-to-create-a-predicate-that-tests-if-a-field-equals/33308391#33308391)

```
// step by step with variables
Function <S,Boolean> predicateFunction = predicate::test;
// a kind of @FunctionalInterface implicit "conversion" ? Predicate -> Function.
// is that safe ?

Function <E,Boolean> composed = function.andThen(predicateFunction::apply);
return composed::apply;
```

---

Edit :

It's called a cast context : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html

```
// the implementation of my compose can also be this ugly one-liner :
return ((Function <S,Boolean>)predicate::test).compose(function)::apply;
```

So, we cannot implement a generic compose function taking any functional interface (in my case Function and Predicate) because the name of the abstract method differs for each interface (test and apply in my case).
I'm OK with that.

To conclude, what I really need is two static functions, one that converts a Predicate to a Function and the opposite. Every Predicate will be used as a Function and the final operation will convert the composed Function to Predicate in order to match with the parameter type of the filter function.

```
public static <S> Function<S,Boolean> predicateToFunction(Predicate<S> predicate){
    return predicate::test;
}
public static <S> Predicate<S> functionToPredicate(Function<S,Boolean> function){
    return function::apply;
}
```

---

Is that correct ?
If so, is there any interest in releasing the bounds in the function signature ?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: The reason the JDK doesn't have this built in is because it's usually simpler just to write the lambda explicitly.

Comment: @JacobG. I edited my post to describe the context.

Comment: How about builder pattern ?

Comment: @Antoniossss Do you mean a new fluent class taking, one by one, a predicate or a function ? Checking the types and composing them all ?
It seems to be far more ambitious than my need but can be interesting.
I just want to validate that my compose function is correct and works in all case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I answer my own questions.

Use lambda :

```
value -> predicate.test(function.apply(value));
```

Or if you really want/have to write a compose function, signature must be something like :

```
public static <E,S> Predicate<E> compose(Function<E,S> function, Predicate<? super S> predicate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be use the boolean compose methods `Predicate` provides: `and`, `or`, `not`. e.g.,

```
private Predicate<String> startsWith(String prefix) {
    return s -> s.startsWith(prefix);
}

private Predicate<String> endsWith(String suffix) {
    return s -> s.endsWith(suffix);
}

Stream.of("Foo","Fuz","Doo","Fo")
    .filter(startsWith("F").and(endsWith("o")))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @fdelsert, here is my implementation of a composition predicate.

I was in the process of removing guava from a project for some reasons.

Guava uses its own version of Predicate and Function to create a Composed Predicate which now is obsolete since Java integrated those into standard function library. I wrote a similar class that follows same signature as Guava but uses POJ classes instead.

Might be useful for future users:

```
public class CompositionPredicate<A, B>
        implements Predicate<A>, Serializable {

    private final Predicate<? super B> predicate;

    private final Function<A, ? extends B> function;

    public CompositionPredicate(Predicate<B> predicate, Function<A, ? extends B> function) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(predicate);
        Objects.requireNonNull(function);
        this.predicate = predicate;
        this.function = function;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof CompositionPredicate<?, ?>) {
            @SuppressWarnings("PatternVariableCanBeUsed") CompositionPredicate<?, ?> that = (CompositionPredicate<?, ?>) obj;
            return function.equals(that.function) && predicate.equals(that.predicate);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return function.hashCode() ^ predicate.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return predicate + "(" + function + ")";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(A a) {
        return predicate.test(function.apply(a));
    }
}
```