# Stream map on filter

Tags: java, java-stream

When you have a Stream of Objects you can filter on them pretty elegantly.

```java
swimmingAnimalStream = animalStream
    .filter(Animal::canSwim);
```

When you have slightly more complex filters instead of using Method references you have to use Lambdas.

```java
greenAnimals = animalStream
    .filter(animal -> animal.getColor().equals(Colors.GREEN));
```

Is there a way to map the value before filtering on it, but still have the complete object after the filter?
So the fallowing is not what I want:

```java
animalStream
    .map(Animal::getColor)
    .filter(Colors.GREEN::equals)
```

With this I would be left with color information only.
What I also would like to avoid is extracting the method. I am looking for a more streamlined way of doing this. Something like this for example:

```java
animalStream
    .filter(Colors.GREEN::equals, Animal::getColor);
```

The method signature of this filter method would look like this.

```java
<MAPPED> Stream<T> filter(Predicate<MAPPED> filter, Function<? super T, MAPPED> mappingFunction);
```

Even better would be a version where you could join multiple mapping functions. On the fly one could maybe use a varargs for the mappingFunction. But I honestly don’t know how that would be possible with Generics. But that’s a different story.

The solution should also be able to use whatever Predicate that one could imagine. Equals is just an Example. Another example would be to check if a field from the object is present.

```java
animalWithMotherStream = animalStream
    .filter(Optional::isPresent, Animal::getMother);
```

Does anyone now a cleaner Solution, or a library that does this already?

Comment: What’s wrong with `.filter(animal -> animal.getColor().equals(Colors.GREEN))`? Is it really about the ten characters you save with the hypothetical `.filter(Colors.GREEN::equals, Animal::getColor)`? Then just use `.filter(a -> a.getColor().equals(Colors.GREEN))`, case closed.

Comment: Reminds me of a question of my own – [Is there a convenience method to create a Predicate that tests if a field equals a given value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300011/is-there-a-convenience-method-to-create-a-predicate-that-tests-if-a-field-equals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Guava's [`Predicates.compose()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.guava/guava/latest/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html#compose(com.google.common.base.Predicate,com.google.common.base.Function)), or create your own:

```
public static <A, B> Predicate<A> compose(
        Predicate<B> predicate, Function<A, ? extends B> function) {
    return a -> predicate.test(function.apply(a));
}
```

Now just pass that into your filter:

```
animalStream.filter(compose(Colors.GREEN::equals, Animal::getColor))
```

As for the varargs concept, I doubt that's possible under Java's generics, unless they're all of the same type, in which case you'd just `apply()` each in a loop or reduce them with `Function.andThen()`.

Comment: short and simple, pretty much exactly what I was looked for, except for the missing varargs part. But like you I also doubt that that’s possible. One could just omit the Generic type or use a Wildcard generic <?>. But I strongly doubt that a library would use that.

Comment: Wildcards wouldn't help. You can't pass anything but null into a `Function<?, ?>`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Java 16

Yes, there is a solution using [`Stream#mapMulti`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) as of Java 16.

```java
animalStream
    .mapMulti((animal, consumer) -> {
        if (Colors.GREEN.equals(animal.getColor())) {  // condition
            consumer.accept(animal);                   // qualify the instance
        }
    })
    ...                                                // further operations
```

The provided `Consumer<R>` accepts the instance that is qualified based on your criteria.

**Pros**: The performance-wise advantage of this imperative approach is that you don't necessarily invoke the two `Stream` operations but just one, for example, a combination of `Stream#map` and `Stream#filter` can be substituted. Though the biggest advantage is that `Consumer#accept` can be invoked as many times as you want, so you can effectively increase a number of entries in a `Stream`.

**Cons**: However, you lost a bit of the declarative approach and if used only as on the snippet without further processing, it's worth using rather a simple for-loop or sticking with the `filter` operation (see below):

#### Older Java versions

Simply write the condition down to `Stream#filter`, it's a correct Stream usage:

```java
animalStream
     .filter(animal -> Colors.GREEN.equals(animal.getColor()))
     ...
```

Comment: In the scope of this question, using `mapMulti()` does not provide any advantage. As you can see in your own answer, the _older_ approach is more readable, and I doubt it would be less efficient (maybe even more). OP is not asking about mapping and filtering at the same time.

Comment: @DidierL I don't agree, the answer seems to fulfil the question and SO is always a good place to learn new ways to handle problems. OP tried to inform us about a new alternative way which was introduced lately with new java version.

Comment: I am very sorry, but I already knew this method, and that was not what I was asking about.

Comment: @DidierL: The authors of questions are requested to post a minimal and reproducible code. It can, however, lead to omitting the context of where and how is the code snippet used. There are situations where `mapMulti` is a good solution, especially for streaming where you need to perform some complex logic. That's why I have provided aside from this option also a description of the pros/cons suggesting when `mapMulti` shall be used.

Comment: I’m not saying `mapMulti` is never useful, I’m saying it isn’t in the scope of this question. In fact, your pros are not relevant here since OP explicitly said in the question that they do not want to perform a `map`, they only need some kind of `filter`. You are simply not answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

`filter` accepts a Predicate, whose function can only return a boolean. [There's no other method signature.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

If you want to filter by all green animals, you'd use

```
animalStream
    .filter(a -> Colors.GREEN.equals(a.getColor()))
```

or

```
Predicate<Animal> isGreen = (a) -> Colors.GREEN.equals(a.getColor());
Stream<Animal> greenAnimals = animalStream.filter(isGreen);
```

Don't use `map` unless you want a `Stream<COLOR>`

> join multiple mapping functions

You can chain them, rather than join - `.stream().map().map()`, but as you discovered, this does not preserve the original type.

Answer (score 1):

[StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex), a library that provides extended stream methods and classes, has [`filterBy`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#filterBy(java.util.function.Function,K)):

> ```
> public <K> StreamEx<T> filterBy​(Function<? super T,​? extends K> mapper, K value)
> ```
>
> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream for which the supplied mapper function returns the given value.
>
> This method behaves like `filter(t -> Objects.equals(value, mapper.apply(t)))`.

Comment: Hey John StreamEx looks promising. But I searched for a more general solution. This one only works when the filter is an equals. I will edit the question to make this clear.

Answer (score 1):

Operation `Stream.filter()` expects a `Predicate` which is a *function* producing a `boolean` result. This definition of the `filter` is very intuitive and self-contained, and there are no other flavors of filter (*and I doubt if they will appear in the future*).

However, you can create your implementation of `Predicate` and give it all the behavior you need. And as a Predicate, it would be eligible to be used in the `filter`.

Before introducing the implementation, I'll show some of the capabilities that can be given to such custom `Predicate`.

```
Stream<Animal> greenAnimals = animalStream
    .filter(
        MultiPred.ofOr(Animal::getColor, Color.WHITE::equals, Color.GREEN::equals)
            .or(
                MultiPred.of(Animal::getType, AnimalType.CARNIVORE::equals)
                .and(Animal::canFly) // we can chain custom Predicates with regular ones
            )
            .or(
                MultiPred.of(Animal::getType, AnimalType.HERBIVORE::equals)
                .and(MultiPred.of(Animal::getColor, Color.PURPLE::equals)
                    .or(Animal::canSwim)
                )
            )
    );
```

Here's a dummy class `Animal` and enums used in the example above:

```
public class Animal {
    private AnimalType type;
    private boolean canSwim;
    private boolean canFly;
    private Color color;
    
    // getters
}

public enum AnimalType {
    CARNIVORE, HERBIVORE
}

public enum Color {
    GREEN, WHITE, PURPLE
}
```

## Implementation

You can provide a custom `Predicate` with any capabilities you require.

The following predicate expects exposes methods expecting a *keyExtractor* function and a predicate, or a group of predicates that has to be chained with either logical OR `||`, or logical AND `&&`.

```
public class MultiPred<T, K> implements Predicate<T> {

    private final BiFunction<Function<T, K>, Predicate<K>, Predicate<T>>
        predicateProducer = (f, p) -> t -> p.test(f.apply(t));
    
    private final Predicate<T> p;
    
    private MultiPred(Function<T, K> keyExtractor,
                      Predicate<K> predicate) {
        
        this.p = predicateProducer.apply(keyExtractor, predicate);
    }
    
    @SafeVarargs
    public static <T, K> MultiPred<T, K> ofAnd(Function<T, K> keyExtractor,
                                               Predicate<K>... predicates) {
        
        return of(keyExtractor, k -> true, Predicate::and, predicates);
    }
    
    @SafeVarargs
    public static <T, K> MultiPred<T, K> ofOr(Function<T, K> keyExtractor,
                                              Predicate<K>... predicates) {
        
        return of(keyExtractor, k -> false, Predicate::or, predicates);
    }
    
    @SafeVarargs
    public static <T, K> MultiPred<T, K> of(Function<T, K> keyExtractor,
                                            Predicate<K> identity,
                                            BinaryOperator<Predicate<K>> op,
                                            Predicate<K>... predicates) {
        
        Objects.requireNonNull(predicates);
        
        Predicate<K> predicate = Arrays.stream(predicates).reduce(identity, op);
        
        return new MultiPred<>(keyExtractor, predicate);
    }
    
    public static <T, K> MultiPred<T, K> of(Function<T, K> keyExtractor,
                                            Predicate<K> predicate) {
        
        Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
        Objects.requireNonNull(predicate);
    
        return new MultiPred<>(keyExtractor, predicate);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean test(T t) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(t);
        return p.test(t);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Predicate<T> and(Predicate<? super T> other) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        return p.and(other);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Predicate<T> negate() {
        return p.negate();
    }
    
    @Override
    public Predicate<T> or(Predicate<? super T> other) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        return p.or(other);
    }
}
```

## Utility Class for constructing Predicates

The logic from the class above can materialized as a utility class exposing a bunch `static` method for generating `Predicate`s. It would preserve all the capacities shown in usage example at the beginning.

*(Credits for this idea belong to @Holger and @shmosel, since he [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74485550/17949945) the static method producing a predicate earlier, hence the code shown below should be considered as built on the answer by @shmosel)*

```
public static class MultiPred {

    private MultiPred() {}

    @SafeVarargs
    public static <T, K> Predicate<T> ofAnd(Function<T, K> keyExtractor,
                                            Predicate<K>... predicates) {
        
        return of(keyExtractor, k -> true, Predicate::and, predicates);
    }
    
    @SafeVarargs
    public static <T, K> Predicate<T> ofOr(Function<T, K> keyExtractor,
                                           Predicate<K>... predicates) {
        
        return of(keyExtractor, k -> false, Predicate::or, predicates);
    }
    
    @SafeVarargs
    public static <T, K> Predicate<T> of(Function<T, K> keyExtractor,
                                         Predicate<K> identity,
                                         BinaryOperator<Predicate<K>> op,
                                         Predicate<K>... predicates) {
        
        Objects.requireNonNull(predicates);
        
        Predicate<K> predicate = Arrays.stream(predicates).reduce(identity, op);
        
        return getPredicateProducer(keyExtractor, predicate);
    }
    
    public static <T, K> Predicate<T> of(Function<T, K> keyExtractor,
                                         Predicate<K> predicate) {
        
        Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
        Objects.requireNonNull(predicate);
        
        return getPredicateProducer(keyExtractor, predicate);
    }
    
    private static <T, K> Predicate<T> getPredicateProducer(Function<T, K> keyExtractor,
                                                            Predicate<K> predicate) {
        return t -> predicate.test(keyExtractor.apply(t));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an unnecessary complication. Why defer the construction of the actual `Predicate` from the `of` method to the `MultiPred` constructor and further to the entirely unnecessary `BiFunction … predicateProducer `? There isn’t even a point in having `MultiPred` as return type, as it doesn’t offer anything the `Predicate` doesn’t already have, just unnecessary wrapping. Change the return types of the factory methods to `Predicate<T>` and change the `return` statements of the `of` methods to `return t -> predicate.test(keyExtractor.apply(t));` and you can remove half of this code.

Comment: @Holger I see, but you have to admit that such `Predicate` can help to resolve type inference issues while chaining predicates without casting. For instance this would fail to compile `filter(Animal::canFly.or(Animal::canSwim).or(...))`, conversely this would compile since implementation has tells what should be the type `filter(MultiPred.of(...).or(Animal::canFly).or(Animal::canSwim))`.

Comment: And how it that different if `MultiPred.of(...)` just returns `Predicate`?

Comment: @Holger And it's also can help to avoid accessing the same property multiple times like in the following scenario: `filter(a -> a.getColor() == Color.WHITE || a.getColor() == Color.GREEN)`. Because it's allows to specify multiple `Predicate`s that would be chained together and used to evaluate the value returned by the *keyExtractor*. Which is a slight advantage. That said, I agree that this thing is an unnecessary complicated, and not suitable for practical use, but the problem itself is slightly contrived.

Comment: You are missing the point. I didn’t object your static factory methods nor their parameters, I just said, those factory methods can simply return `Predicate`. Then, the static factory methods are all you need. There is no reason for `MultiPred` to implement `Predicate` nor wrap a `Predicate`. If you keep the four static methods and remove the obsolete rest, you have half the code.

Comment: To demonstrate that it works if all unnecessary things are removed, https://ideone.com/6sNBP3

Comment: @Holger Sorry for dumb comments. I've got your point, I've followed your advice and implemented this functionality as static. And I also observed that, in a nutshell, that's precisely what `@shmosel` was proposing, approved his answer.

Comment: thank you all for all this Information. I will have a look at this. But from a user perspective its quite a lot. That’s why I accepted the way shorter Answer from @shmosel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late, but this has not been proposed yet.

StreamEx has been already mentioned, but its usage may vary ;)

```
greenAnimals = StreamEx.of(animalStream)
    .mapToEntry(Animal::getColor)
    .filterValues(Colors.GREEN::equals)
    .keys();

animalWithMotherStream = StreamEx.of(animalStream)
    .mapToEntry(Animal::getMother)
    .removeValues(Optional::isEmpty)
    .keys();
```

The general approach is to map an implicit 'Entry' from the streamed objects themselves (as keys) AND a property of those objects (as values).
Then you can use whatever you want on the values and finally return the keys.